# How to receive data from aws sqs in laravel?

Tags: laravel, amazon-sqs, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am trying to implement `amazon sp-api notifications` in the docs. They have written that they will send a notification to destination `aws sqs`. I am trying to figure out how I will get that notification from sqs. I have tried research about it but not found any luck.

is there any can please explain?